# Create Image from layout with android sdk

Tags: android, image, android-layout, sdk, preview

For my project, I need a kind of live layout preview of my android layouts inside my application.

Is it possible to generate an image from my layout like for example Android Studio does it, by using the android sdk with shell commands?